# Assigning a division value in PDDL 2.1 , Metric FF

Tags: planning, pddl

I have 3 variables in functions section:

```
(x)
(y)
(z)
```

I have initialized all of them to `0` in my problem `init`.

An action in my domain changes the value of `x` and `y`.

Now when I try to assign the value of `x/y` to `z` , it says it is not a linear task.

```
(assign (z) (/ (x) (y) ) )
```

But when I write `(assign (z) (/ (x) 2 ) )` it assigned correct value which is `x/2`, similarly `(assign (z) (/ (y) 2 ) )` it is assigned correct value `(y/2)`. This ensured that x and y are not zeroes.

Now why `(assign (z) (/ (x) (y) ) )` is not working? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Metric-FF does not support non-linear expressions, as the one you are using to assign the value to variable z. Try making x and y constant (remove any action modifying them), and see that it will work, yet that may not be what you are looking for. For non-linear expressions in numeric planning problems have a look at ENHSP: https://sites.google.com/view/enhsp/